# T-SQL - dynamic parameter in stored procedere

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to use dynamic date parameter in a stored procedure between `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `BEGIN`?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MYSP 
    @StartDate DATETIME = GETDATE(),
    @EndDate DATETIME = GETDATE() - 1
BEGIN
AS
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not clear... Wouldn't declaring `DATE` parameter suffice?

Comment: BEGIN should start after AS not before and are you sure EndDate is one day before the StartDate?

Comment: this is the start of my parameter declaration CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Tableau_Test_SP_Parameter
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @StartDate DATETIME=CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),101)
AS
BEGIN but it is giving me a syntax error on CONVERT and GETDATE()

Answer (score 2):

You can't add `GETDATE()` default parameter to stored procedure. Instead of this you can do this :

```
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.MYSP 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MYSP 
    @StartDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @EndDate DATETIME = NULL
AS
BEGIN
IF @StartDate IS NULL SET @StartDate=GETDATE()
IF @EndDate IS NULL SET @EndDate=DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())

SELECT @StartDate,@EndDate

END
GO
dbo.MYSP
```